# How do you stop ADT Logcat View from automatically popping up in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, view

It's really annoying and I guess there was an option for this ( [How do you stop Console from popping up automatically in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462520/how-do-you-stop-console-from-popping-up-automatically-in-eclipse) ) but I don't see that, at least not in ADT. It's really annoying. Btw, if someone knows a way to keep the entire tab below (the one with problems, logcat, console, etc) to keep minimized until I decide that they should show up, that would help

Comment: not a duplicate. disabling eclipse's console pop up options don't affect the ADT's error logging pop-up behavior.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9352065/350040

Answer (score -1):

The Run/Debug->Console preference page also offers those options.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. Especially when Eclipse is still loading the projects in the workspace. It's a pain, you have to wait 5 minutes until it finishes, better than getting interrupted by the window every 5 seconds

Comment: What's it doing with the Console while you're loading projects?

Comment: it keeps showing up in front of my editor so I have to change view all the time. It's usually errors in other projects that in the moment I don't have any interest in knowing about.

Comment: @nitind, It's not the console that's causing the problem but the messages in `LogCat`. There doesn't seem to be a way to stop `LogCat` from appearing automatically.