# Logcat pops up automatically in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat, ddms

I am having this problem.  The logcat pops up automatically in eclipse when I am running or debugging an android. Extremely annoyed. How to stop this?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? And what is actually annoying you?

Comment: Go to the Android > LogCat section of Eclipse>window> Prefereneces, its the area for logcat settings

Comment: @RemeesMSyde, **Doesn't work.** There's no settings there to change this behavior.

Comment: @user2103379, See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9352065/632951